# Php parse content from url by class name

Tags: php

I can not find the right parsing solution from another link. I want to parse content from part of site.

I need get string "Director".

```
<div>
    <div class="jobtitle">Director</div>
</div>
```

This is code display all content from link

```
$url = 'somelink.com';
$result = file_get_contents($url);

echo($result);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please ?

Comment: Show us your `parse()` function and tell us what does not work as expected - actual vs. expected outcome. And let us know in detail what you've tried to debug your code. Please read [ask]

Comment: Do you want to retrieve content of elements that has a certain class? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes absolutely

Comment: @jibsteroos thanks, i edited my post, please see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Simple HTML DOM Parser - how to get the element which has certain content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060170/php-simple-html-dom-parser-how-to-get-the-element-which-has-certain-content)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i will try and give feedback, thnk

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks for library, best solution for my task.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$url = 'somelink.com';
$result = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result);

$classname="jobtitle";
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

Or if you don't want to use XPath traversal, you can simply loop throught all the div nodes and get the `class` attribute that is equal to "jobtitle".

This is the code:

```
$url = 'somelink.com';
$result = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($result);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName ("div");

$wanted_node ;

foreach( $nodes $n) {
    if ($n->getAttribute('class') == "jobtitle"){
        $wanted_node = $n;
    }
}

//If wanted_node is not null(the node with class=jobtitle is found
if (isset ($wanted_node)){
    echo $wanted_node;
}
```